# How do I load an object once in the lifetime of Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have an object that takes a few mins to load. This object must be available to all other modules and I want to load this into memory for as long as the Node.js process is running and load it again only when the Node.js process is restarted

```
rs.loadDirectory(path,
        (batchNumber) => {
            b.onLoadSuccessful(userId, session)
        },
        (error, batchNumber) => {
            b.onLoadFailed(error, batchNumber, session);
        });
```

When the loading is complete, I would like to export rs to be used by other modules. Any suggestions

**UPDATE 1**
I found [THIS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/once) library that calls a function once, can someone please clarify if this library is suitable for the above usecase

Comment: Cache the result.  If the function is called a second time, return the first result.  Promises can make that really easy.  You create a promise that represents the first time you load it.  Cache the promise.  Anytime someone calls the function, you return the promise to which they apply a `.then()` handler to and get the result.  Works first time, second time, 1000th time, always returning the result that was first retrieved.

Comment: thanks for the comment @jfriend would I need any caching libraries for node

Comment: [Using a promise for a cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259371/how-to-hold-a-nodejs-application-until-other-promise-completes/34259604#34259604).  No caching library needed.

Comment: You can cache that in external DB like redis!

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty it doesnt seem like redis stores custom objects in it " It supports data structures such as strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets with range queries, bitmaps, hyperloglogs and geospatial indexes with radius queries." taken from their docs

Comment: ahh! I see! thanks for the explanation buddy!